# TensorFlow tf.decode_csv() not recognizing end of line character

Tags: csv, tensorflow

I am trying to read in a CSV file in TensorFlow.

```
record_defaults = [[0.0], [0.0]]
data = tf.decode_csv(r"C:\Users\USER.NAME\Desktop\tmp.txt", record_defaults=record_defaults)
sess = tf.InteractiveSession(config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True))

sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

print(sess.run(data))

sess.close()
```

Where tmp.txt is a simple CSV:

```
1.0,4.0
-.3,1.2
```

Note that I am running windows and Notepad++ shows that my lines end with '\r\n' (CRLF).

I get the following error when running the above code, which suggests to me that tensorflow isnt recognizing the end of line character:

```
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in 
_do_call(self, fn, *args)

   1021     try:
-> 1022       return fn(*args)
   1023     except errors.OpError as e:

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in _run_fn(session, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, options, run_metadata)
   1003                                  feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list,
-> 1004                                  status, run_metadata)
   1005 

C:\Anaconda3\Lib\contextlib.py in __exit__(self, type, value, traceback)
     65             try:
---> 66                 next(self.gen)
     67             except StopIteration:

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\errors_impl.py in raise_exception_on_not_ok_status()
    465           compat.as_text(pywrap_tensorflow.TF_Message(status)),
--> 466           pywrap_tensorflow.TF_GetCode(status))
    467   finally:

InvalidArgumentError: Expect 2 fields but have 1 in record 0
     [[Node: DecodeCSV = DecodeCSV[OUT_TYPE=[DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT], field_delim=",", _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](DecodeCSV/records, DecodeCSV/record_defaults_0, DecodeCSV/record_defaults_1)]]
```

The error persists even when I change the delimiter to a space or tab.

I've searched across Google/StackOverflow but haven't been able to find a similar error. Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Convert your file to `unix` format. I am assuming you are working on windows. Either way, in Notepad++, change the type of file as below:
From the "Edit" menu, select "EOL Conversion" -> "UNIX/OSX Format".

[Convert to Unix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/swwHD.png)